# Pandas datatime format incorrect when reading from SQL and writing to parquet

Tags: pandas, dataframe

I am relatively new to pandas. I am testing connectivity to a SQL DB and writing the result of a sql query to a parquet file.
I have an issue with the datetime columns being formatted as Epoch datetime. How can I avoid this occurring.

```
sql = 'Select ' + columnsname +' FROM ' + tablename
print(sql)
dfsql = pd.read_sql (sql,cnxn)
dfsql.to_parquet('/NightWalk/Original/'+file+'_sql.parquet')
```

Comment: It would be great to see results of the values and the datetime format that gives you the function, and also it would be great to see what libraries do you use to connect into the db and make the connection in sql; Every variable that you use it would have a context info in the question to know exactly what you used. More information you add to your question the community can help you better and faster.

Answer (score 0):

Before you call `to_parquet` you should probably convert the datetime columns to the correct datatype using `pd.to_datetime`:

```
sql = 'Select ' + columnsname + ' FROM ' + tablename
dfsql = pd.read_sql (sql, cnxn)

# Convert date columns to datetime
dfsql["date_col"] = pd.to_datetime("date_col", unit="ns")

dfsql.to_parquet('/NightWalk/Original/' + file + '_sql.parquet')
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all it would be great to know if you are using `fastparquet` or `pyarrow` libraries, to use `DataFrame.to_parquet()`function you have to use one of them, it is important to know what do you use for parquet parsing.

### First aproaches

To the question

> I have an issue with the datetime columns being formatted as Epoch datetime. How can I avoid this occurring.

As far as i know, that can´t be handle, because `to_parquet` function works with **timestamps format** whether you are *reading from a parquet file* or *saving into a parquet file*.

The only way to change that dates, are using convert functions similar to @Ashyam answer or something like

```
import pandas as pd
import 

sql = 'Select ' + columnsname + ' FROM ' + tablename
dfsql = pd.read_sql (sql, cnxn)

def convert_timestamps_to_dates_df(df):
    for col in df.columns:
        if df[col].dtype == "datetime64[ns]":
            df[col] = df[col].dt.date
    return df


convert_timestamps_to_dates_df(dfsql).to_parquet(file + ".parquet")
```

### Conclusions

If you are going to use parquets files, you will have to use convert functions to handle **EPOCH TIME FORMAT**.